# Corresponding group ID not added to the process of the application

Tags: android, linux, android-permissions

Adb command `adb shell dumpsys package com.hackerli.girl` can help me get application info.

Before I request `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  permission, my app has a `gids=[3003]`.

```
requested permissions:
  android.permission.INTERNET
  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
install permissions:
  android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
User 0: ceDataInode=1531967 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=false enabled=0
  gids=[3003]
  runtime permissions:
User 999: ceDataInode=0 installed=false hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0
  gids=[3003]
  runtime permissions:
```

After runtime permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted, I get below info.

```
requested permissions:
  android.permission.INTERNET
  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
install permissions:
  android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
User 0: ceDataInode=1531967 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
  gids=[3003]
  runtime permissions:
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=true
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=true
User 999: ceDataInode=0 installed=false hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0
  gids=[3003]
  runtime permissions:
```

As you see, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is also granted since it belongs to as same group as `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. **However the `gids` is not changed. I think it should be updated so is there anything I mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary

The `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is now (> API 23) implemented as a *built-in* android permission and is now managed by the runtime. Earlier (< API 23) the permission was part the *low-level kernel* enforced group of permission implemented as [**Linux Supplementary Group**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_370), i.e, by assigning the groups to the App on install time.

### Behaviour prior to Marshmallow (< API 23)

Before Marshmallow (specifically before introduction of [Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)), the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was implemented at *kernel level*. Whenever any process try to access the external storage, the call goes through the kernel (the [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall) where the kernel checked the permissions of the calling process (usual Linux stuff...). For the *geeks* this is how the call-stack looks like:

1. To read a [`File`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) you open a stream to it using the [`FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). When we construct a [`FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), this calls [`IOBridge.open(String, int)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#87). [`IOBridge`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoBridge.java) is an internal class and delegates the opening to *native* JNI-call.
2. Inside the [`IOBridge.open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoBridge.java#437) call, the method delegates to [`Libcore.os.open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoBridge.java#442). Again [`Libcore`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/Libcore.java) is an internal class.
3. The [`Libcore.os.open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/Posix.java#109) is a native method, implemented [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/native/libcore_io_Posix.cpp#1030). And [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-mr1-release/luni/src/main/native/libcore_io_Posix.cpp#1035), the method calls the [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall and the kernel kicks-in!

### Behaviour starting Marshmallow (>= API 23)

Starting with Marshmallow (with introduction of [Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)) developers are required to ask for the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from the user. This changes the way the permission is assigned to the app. Android still assigns *normal* permissions at *install* time but for *dangerous* app Android requires the app to display a popup asking for the permission. When the user grants the permission, the `PackageManager` records it and adds it to the app's database record (in `/data/system/packages.xml`). If the permission is a *low-level* permission, i.e., implemented by *kernel* using *groups* then the `PackageManager` adds the app's user id to the corresponding group too.
Earlier the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was implemented as a *low-level* permission (hence managed by kernel) but now the app is implemented as a *built-in* permission managed by runtime.
The call-stack now looks like:

1. To read a [`File`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) you open a stream to it using the [`FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). When we construct a [`FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), which calls the private [`FileOutputStream.open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/ojluni/src/main/java/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#221) native function implemented [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/ojluni/src/main/native/FileOutputStream_md.c#55).
2. The native [`FileOutputStream.open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/ojluni/src/main/native/FileOutputStream_md.c#55) calls the helper [`fileOpen()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/ojluni/src/main/native/io_util_md.c#66) which delegates call to [`JVM_Open()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/ojluni/src/main/native/io_util_md.c#77) implemented by runtime and thus the runtime now manages the permission.

Because the app is not added to the group, so it is not displayed in `dumpsys`.

For more details about permissions and security on Android, I would recommend you read [Android Security Internals by Nikolay Elenkov](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Android_Security_Internals.html?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)